# Regla de tres con cinco parametros ¿Regla de cinco?

Tags: matemáticas

Noo consigo sacar la formula de esto, es una regla de 3, pero en vez de de 3, de 5. No se que nombre tendrá esto, per seria algo asi:

5000 - 10

2000 - 5

2375 - x

Es decir:

Si 5000 es 10

Y Si 2000 es 5

Entonces 2375 es X

¿cual es la formula de esto? Tiene pinta de ser una chorrada pero no lo saco…

gracias!

Comment: ¿En qué lenguaje de programación? ¿Los números son simpre esos o pueden variar? Con esto quiero saber si se les pasa por parámetro al método que lo haga o si pides los números por consola

Comment: realmente lo que quiero es la formula, ya luego lo paso yo al lenguaje de programación, no hay problema. Pero vamos, Java mismamente. Y los números vendrian por parametro. El 2375 sería realmente el parametro, los otros serían los fijos.

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque no es sobre programación, es sobre matemáticas

Comment: Este sitio es sobre programacion, no matematicas...Por favor no hacer preguntas que no correspondan...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que yo haría para resolver este problema sería ver cada par de números como un punto (x,y). Así el primer punto sería (10,5000), el segundo (5,2000) y el tercero sería la parte de la recta que une los dos puntos anteriores con y = 2375.

Lo primero que debemos hacer es calcular la ecuación de la recta sabiendo dos puntos, para ello te recomiendo este enlace https://sites.google.com/site/geometriaanalitica3o/unidad-2/ecuacion-de-la-recta-que-pasa-por-dos-puntos .
La ecuación de la recta que nos sale es 600x-y-1000=0.
Ahora sabiendo que y = 2375, resolvemos la ecuación y nos sale x = 5.625.

Comment: Muchas gracias!! :D Es justo lo que necesitaba

Comment: Esta pregunta no deberia haber sido contestaad

Answer (score 1):

tu problema es matemático, no se puede usar una regla con tus datos pues no siguen una proporción lineal,

es decir si 5000->10 debería ser la mitad 2500->5 para usar la regla de 3.

en tu caso es 2000->5 ( y no 2500)

Lo que debes hacer es ajustar a un polinomio todos los datos (parejas de datos)que tengas

("x" los pequeños e "y" los grandes)

1    2     3    4.............5.............10......... x

a    b...............2000...... ..50000.......y

Para ello hay muchos programas  en internet
que son  para sacar la función de interpolación( interpolar es sacar nuevos datos desde los que tienes)

Te data un polinomio de grado "n-1". dependiendo del numero de pareja de datos que tengas, entiendo que también tienes el dato (0,0).

En este enlace te saca la formula.

https://www.geogebra.org/m/PpvAZU6j

Pones primero el nº de parejas por defecto 5
y pones los datos (de 2 en dos) con comas, ejemplo (5,2000)  y también (10,5000)
Marcas la casilla de polinomio de grado n
y se sale la curva y abajo el polinómio
Saludos. (ya no es una recta claro, no es lineal)
Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, respondió antes Francisco, pero gracias de todas maneras :)

Comment: Esta pregunta no deberia haber sido contestada